# How do I make a variable equal to multiple items?

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to make this variable equal to the user id and then a random integer that comes straight after the user id. How would I do this as my code doesn't seem to work?

```
$parentid = $_SESSION['user_name'] + rand();
```

Thanks

Comment: Explain _"my code doesn't seem to work"_ and what steps you have done to debug the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is beginner error, string concat is done using a single dot `.`

Anyway I suggest you using [mt_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) function that is 4 time faster than the oldest [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function

So your code should be something like this

```
$parentid = $_SESSION['user_name'] . mt_rand();
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more "strict" guideline, you could use `sprintf` or `str_replace()`

```
$parentid = sprintf('%s%d', $_SESSION['username'], rand());
```